# Combine the figure into one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want these two separate plot into one . How can i do that ? The two plots are representing the numbers in the list dis . First correspods to 20 and other corresponds to 40. Similarly, it can be done for various other numbers.
[image]

```
dis=[20,40]
b=0
f=25/60
time=10
t_i=0.001
mean=0.03
std=0.00666
r=0.2
w=2*np.pi*300/60
v=2*np.pi*r*300/60
avg=0.03

high=2
xm=np.linspace(0,2,500)
ym=high
while b<=len(dis)-1:
    n=2*3.14*dis[b]*r/(avg*100)
    s=np.random.normal(mean,std,round(n))
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(12,2))
    for i in s:   
        t=np.arange(0.1,time,t_i) 
        k=r+i
        c=v/k
        m=np.sqrt((k**2-(k-0.01)**2)/k)
        j=np.arcsin(m)
        x=k*(np.sin((c*t)+j))+f*t
        y=k*(np.cos((c*t)+j))
        ax.set_xlim([0.3,2])
        ax.set_ylim([y.min()-0.05,-0.1])
        reversed = False
        ind0=0
        while ind0 < len(x):
            ind1 = ind0 + 1
            if reversed:
                while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] <= x[ind1 - 1]:
                    ind1 += 1
                ym = np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1][::-1], y[ind0:ind1][::-1], left=high, right=high))
            else:
                while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] >= x[ind1 - 1]:
                    ind1 += 1
                ym=np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1], y[ind0:ind1], left=high, right=high))
            ind0 = ind1
            reversed = not reversed
    ax.set_xlabel('x (mm)')
    ax.set_ylabel('y (mm)')
    ax.plot(xm, ym, color='r', alpha=0.5)
    b+=1
```

Comment: You can avoid most of your loops by vectorizing your calculations. Instead of creating a range and iterating over it: `dis=[20,40].... while b<=len(dis)-1:`, just create an array: `np.arange(20,40)` and use array or matrix operations. b) Don't overwrite the builtin  `reversed` c) Your code could use a review, post it on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) d) Please edit the question to add the definition of `dis`, otherwise this is irreproducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to plot both lines into a single plot region. In this case, you should adapt your code as follows.

Note that you are creating new `fig, ax` objects in your while loop, so every time you are plotting something, it is in a new figure. Instead, you want to set up your figure and axes before the while loop, so that you keep adding plots in the same figure. The simplest adaptation of your code to achieve this is as follows:

```
# variables left out for brevity

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 2))

while b<=len(dis)-1:
    n=2*3.14*dis[b]*r/(avg*100)
    s=np.random.normal(mean,std,round(n))
    for i in s:   
        t=np.arange(0.1,time,t_i) 
        k=r+i
        c=v/k
        m=np.sqrt((k**2-(k-0.01)**2)/k)
        j=np.arcsin(m)
        x=k*(np.sin((c*t)+j))+f*t
        y=k*(np.cos((c*t)+j))
        ax.set_xlim([0.3,2])
        ax.set_ylim([y.min()-0.05,-0.1])
        reversed = False
        ind0=0
        while ind0 < len(x):
            ind1 = ind0 + 1
            if reversed:
                while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] <= x[ind1 - 1]:
                    ind1 += 1
                ym = np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1][::-1], y[ind0:ind1][::-1], left=high, right=high))
            else:
                while ind1 < len(x) and x[ind1] >= x[ind1 - 1]:
                    ind1 += 1
                ym=np.minimum(ym, np.interp(xm, x[ind0:ind1], y[ind0:ind1], left=high, right=high))
            ind0 = ind1
            reversed = not reversed
    ax.set_xlabel('x (mm)')
    ax.set_ylabel('y (mm)')
    ax.plot(xm, ym, color='r', alpha=0.5)
    b+=1
```

This gives the following figure:

[image: two lines in the same plot]

Comment: Thank you so much. I want surface plot for the same. We can do the steps right for it ?

Comment: In matplotlib, you can always add plots to an `ax` to plot them in the same figure. However, do note that surface plots might not be suitable for having multiple in the same figure, depending on how you draw them exactly.

Comment: Actually this is a surface roughness plot which is combination of various plot like (20,40).

Comment: Can you help in figuring out how should i proceed for the surface plot ?

Comment: If you provide example code and how you want the plot to look, then I might be able to help. I cannot guess what you want to plot.